# Multiple desktops on a Belkin Router

Tags: router

I have a Belkin wireless router hooked up presently to a desktop. I just purchased a new desktop and would like to use the same router. I have connected a ethernet cable directly to a port on the router to the desktop. However on the new desktop it states that the cable is not connected/no good and try a new one. I know the cable is OK.Is there something that has to be installed on the new desktop to recognize the router. I also checked for devices on the new desktop and cannot see an ethernet connection????

Answer (score 0):

sounds to me that the ethernet port is either disabled, or you have the cable plugged in wrong.

Go to your networking center in windows, then go to Adapter Settings --> see if its disabled in there, if so, enable it.

If nothing is there, then there's a problem. Either your device is disabled in the Device Manager, or is uninstalled (no driver), or is busted.

Right click on "Computer" then go to "Manage" --> go down to Device Manager and expand the tree for networking devices. See if you have your ethernet port there.